# Formula for bisector segment of a given lenght between two segments

Tags: geometry, angle, bisection

I've got the (x,y) coords of three points defining two connected segments; I need to find the coordinates of the two bisectors, of a chosen lenght, at the angle between the two segments.

I have already searched around but the problem is: math is not my thing at all, so even solutions I've found are really obscure to me. And I need to translate this into a computer script where I have no matrixes or vectors support, so I'd really need the plain formulas...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$1)$ Suppose $A(x_a,y_a)$ and $B(x_b,y_b)$ then $M((x_a+x_b)/2,(y_a+y_b)/2)$

and the bisector will be:

$$y=-\left(\frac{x_a-x_b}{y_a-y_b}\right)x+\left(\frac{x_a-x_b}{y_a-y_b}\right)\left(\frac{x_a+x_b}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{y_a+y_b}{2}\right)$$

$2)$ For the angle: You have three points:$A(x_a,y_a), B(x_b,y_b), C(x_a,y_a)$. $B$ is the meeting point.

You need find the vector $\overrightarrow{BA}$ and $\overrightarrow{BC}$ and use Dot Product.

$$\overrightarrow{BA}\cdot \overrightarrow{BC}=|\overrightarrow{BA}||\overrightarrow{BC}|\cos (\angle ABC)$$.

Comment: Hi @motoDrizzt, is it clear?